# Calculate the flux

Tags: calculus

The vector field  $F=-xy^2i-x^2yj+z(x^2+y^2)k$.
(a) Calculate the divergence of F.
(b) A cylinder of height h and radius R has its base in the xy-plane and its axis of symmetry along the z-axis. Calculate the flux of F over the curved portion S of the surface of the cylinder.

I calculated the divergence of F which is equal to zero. My question is if the divF is zero, the flux over the top, the bottom, and the wall of the cylinder are zero, isn't it? But this is not right, otherwise, I would not be asked to calculate the flux. I think the flux of the bottom is equal to zero since z=0, the flux of the top is negative over the portion S. If I am right, then how to calculate the flux of the top?
Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "the flux of every side of the cylinder is zero"?  If you mean the net flux of $F$ across the surface of the cylinder is zero, then yes.  This is immediate by the divergence theorem.

Comment: I mean the flux over the top, bottom and curved portion of the surface(wall) of the cylinder is zero.